# Redeclare UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor in a view in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, push-notification

```
@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
appDelegate.registerPushNotifications()
```

This is what i'm trying to do. **registerPushNotifcations()** is a function inside my delegate.

I'd also like to understand if this is the correct approach and/or does it have any risks associated with it?

Answer (score 0):

The [docs are explicit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiapplicationdelegateadaptor#) about this:

> Define the delegate adaptor only in your App declaration, and only once for a given app. If you declare it more than once, SwiftUI generates a runtime error.

If you need access to the app delegate elsewhere, the docs continue:

> You can access the delegate from any scene or view in your app using the `EnvironmentObject` property wrapper:
>
> ```
> @EnvironmentObject private var appDelegate: MyAppDelegate
> ```